# How to log web request and response in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-mvc

I want to know what parts of my web page the users use and then present it in a nice graphic interface. The only thing I could come up with was this:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseResource dbr;

    @RequestMapping("/foobar")
    public String getFoobar(Principal principal, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req) {
    dbr.logVisit(req); //write the request to a database
 //...
```

At each @RequestMapping I write the request to the database. Is this the best way to do it?

Does it exists a library for this so I do not have to write it all my self? A package that works a bit like Eclipse Usage Data Collector.

I'm using Spring and Spring Security.

Comment: Access logging is the appserver's job, not the application's.

Comment: use can do this with SPring AOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor), this feature is specificaly designed to implement features like this.

Another approach is to use [Logback Access](http://logback.qos.ch/access.html) that tightly and seamlessly integrates with Tomcat.